Line Art using Grease Pencil not working in Panoramic Render for 360 Image/Video
so I have made an object (cabinet/cupboard) in another blend file including the textures nodes and line art using grease pencil, after that I linked the file to another project to composition it with other objects for the final scene render. I use Panoramic Render (Equirectangular) (Cycles Engine) but it seems the line art I made for the object turns into an outline and the size is too big after I tried rendering an image.

Hi krunj, can you upload your .blend file through Blend Exchange so we can have a look, please?

I suspect the line art modifier doesn't work with equirectangular camera and it is using the regular perspective method.

I guess baking line-art could help you.
*Line-art is calculated related to the camera's position, so try to do these steps:
1) Duplicate the stroke you using as many times as many objects you have.
2) Set each stroke to work with a single object:  Source Type> Object
3) Select your first line-arted object
4)  Using Perspective camera mode - set the camera's position with which lines look the best way for this particular object
5) Staying in the Perspective camera mode – bake the line art for this object
6) Then using Perspective camera – bake strokes this way for every object
7) After strokes for all objects are baked - from Perspective Camera switch to Panoramic Render

*I believe this should work, though I recommend you at first to bake strokes for a couple of objects, and if in Panoramic Render baked strokes look well  – bake all of them.
**By the way, Bake option is under the stroke's modifier tab:

